# Place my javascript at the end of the source code for the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, sitefinity

I am writing a piece of javascript to modify a breadcrumb on my page, the breadcrumb is being loaded dynamically by `Sitefinity` through a script after the entire page is loaded. See Below for the script that loads the breadcrumb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
;(function() {
                        function loadHandler() {
                            var hf = $get('ctl05_TSSM');
                            if (!hf._RSSM_init) { hf._RSSM_init = true; hf.value = ''; }
                            hf.value += ';Telerik.Sitefinity.Resources, Version=7.1.5200.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b28c218413bdf563:en:e8482271-e037-4f4c-9782-d3ef83d41650:7a90d6a;Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2014.2.618.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4:en:75278af3-5298-4076-a167-6de45b7d14f0:580b2269:eb8d8a8e';
                            Sys.Application.remove_load(loadHandler);
                        };
                        Sys.Application.add_load(loadHandler);
                    })();Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Telerik.Web.UI.RadSiteMap, null, null, null, $get("ctl00_cph_header_T1D6EFA53006_ctl00_ctl00_Breadcrumb"));
});
//]]>
</script>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the script that places the breadcrumb on the page is right at the end of source code for the page, just before the closing `body` tag.

I need to be able to modify the breadcrumb so I wrote my own little script. The problem I am having is, no matter where I place my little script on the page, when the page loads, my script is always above the script that loads the breadcrumb. As a result, trying to access the elements in the breadcrumb from my code is returning UNDEFINED.

I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //my code
});

window.load(function(){
   //my code
});

window.bind("load",function(){
   //my code
});
```

None of these seem to place/execute my script after the existing script(breadcrumb load) on the page.

Anyone can direct me towards a workaround for this?

Comment: May be Sitefinity affect at the script.

Comment: Guess: `Sys.Application.add_init(callback)` is asynchronous. Try adding your code to the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Create a js file named scripts.js then insert your custom piece of script there with this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //my code
});
```

And place this script.js at the bottom of the head tag

Answer (score 0):

The $create script that you see actually does not load the breadcrumb - it just initializes the Telerik's sitemap javascript object.

Do you want to work with that js object?

If you just want to do something with the html of the breadcrumb - then you should be able to do so with the way you are doing it on document ready.